# simple_html_dom throws warning

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

Using **simple_html_dom** it is only parsing the web page header & then throws an warning;

the error log
Warning: file_get_contents

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.rxproxy.com/index.php?rxproxyuri=aHR0cDovL3N0YXRpYy5pc29odW50LmNvbS9qcy9pc29odW50LmNzcw%3D%3D" type="text/css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.rxproxy.com/index.php?rxproxyuri=aHR0cDovL3N0YXRpYy5pc29odW50LmNvbS9mYXZpY29uLmljbw%3D%3D">
```

ON line 75 of simple_html_dom.php

i noticed there is no ending tag for the 2nd shortcut icon, will this throw the error?

the error log

Comment: The beginning and end of you doctype is missing.

Comment: there was an ending doctype tag on the page that i was using, stackoverflow did not allow it when i posted for some reason

Comment: If that in any way resembles the error message you actually received, then it's more likely that you're attempting to pass HTML, or perhaps a URL, to a function expecting a filename.

Comment: i think that's the answer, over-examined ><

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
  <!doctype html>
```

Should be like this.

Comment: Depends on whether the OP is targeting HTML 5.  The existing doctype is just about correct for HTML 4; it just could stand to have the DTD url (`"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"`) at the end, in order to ensure it kicks browsers into standards mode.

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the start tag (<) for both stylesheet links. EDIT: after the edit you have the start tags.

And yes you need to close the second one.

Comment: No, you don't need to close `<link>` elements; in fact, [HTML 4 *forbids* it](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html#h-12.3).  If you do need to break HTML in order for the parse to work, then that just confirms my findings that simple_html_dom is a steaming pile.